# JS. Convert format date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have date in this format:

`var date`:

> Fri May 31 2013 17:41:01 GMT+0200 (CEST)

How to convert this to: `31.05.2013`

?

Comment: possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript/1056730#1056730

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** This answer is good if you've to handle dates and times often. Maybe it's what you're looking for. It made my work much easier. It's worth a look. If it's just about this simple task, don't load a new script.

I recomment moment.js: http://momentjs.com/

Simple coded example:

```
var date = new Date("Fri May 31 2013 17:41:01 GMT+0200 (CEST)");
var date_str = moment(date).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
alert(date_str);
```

Try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/bvaLt/

Comment: Loading a whole library solely to get the date is totaly stupid. Unless he really wants to work a lot with the time and date he should stay away from that, performance wise.

Comment: @Ghillied Of course he shouldn't load a library just for this simple task. But why should I post an answer twice? It's just another solution and maybe the right one if he didn't know momentjs yet. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertDate(str){
  var d = new Date(str);
  return addZero(d.getDate())+"."+addZero(d.getMonth()+1)+"."+d.getFullYear();
}

//If we have the number 9, display 09 instead
function addZero(num){
  return (num<10?"0":"")+num;
}

convertDate("Fri May 31 2013 17:41:01 GMT+0200 (CEST)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a formatter, go for:

```
('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.' +
('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + 
date.getFullYear()
```

Answer (score 0):

If `d` is a `Date` Object (and not a string representing the date) you may use this approach

```
var d = new Date();

("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "." + 
("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "." + 
d.getFullYear();
```

otherwise, if you have a string, as a first step just pass it into the `Date` constructor as argument

```
var d = new Date("Fry May 31...");
```

Comment: You should add 1 to the month (see my answer), otherwise we are now in May :)